# sp_column not considering @Column_name

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, adventureworks

I'm reading the [official Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) about `sp_columns` and I'm trying to retrieve only one specific column from `AdventureWorks2016.dbo.Person.Address`:

```
exec sp_columns @table_name = 'Person.Address', @Column_name = 'NULLABLE'
```

SSMS is retrieving all all columns as empty

[image]

The Microsoft documentation says I can use `@Column_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute this:

```
exec sp_columns @table_name = 'Address'
```

You should get the following:

[image]

How ever the `@Column_name = 'NULLABLE'` does not exist in the table

[image]

And if you run the query with the correct name of the column you will get it working.

For example this:

```
exec sp_columns @table_name = 'Address', @Column_name = 'AddressID'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `@table_name` parameter value must be the table name alone. Specify the schema name separately using the `@table_owner` column and specify the name of an existing column with the `@column_name` parameter value:

```
exec sp_columns @table_name = N'Address', @table_owner = N'Person', @column_name = N'AddressLine1';
```

Schema and owner are conceptually different in modern SQL Server versions but this is a rather old stored procedure where schema and table owner are used interchangeably.